# Thermodynamic Limit of Entanglement-Entropy like quantities

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, ground-state, tensor-network

Suppose i have, in one spatial dimension, a unique ground state $\Omega$ of a local, gapped, translational invariant Hamiltonian. Denote by $\sigma_s$ the density matrix of $\Omega$ on lattice sites $\{1,...,s\}$. I deal with a certain functional, namely
$$
f(s) := \text{Tr}_{\{1,...,s\}}(\mathcal{N}(\sigma_s) \sigma_s) \ ,
$$
where $\mathcal{N}$ is a partial transpose operation with respect to a subset of $\{1,...,s\}$. For definiteness, take $s$ to be even, and let $\mathcal{N}$ the operation that transposes with respect to the first $s/2$ sites.

I would like to prove, or disprove, that $(f(s))_{s\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. It would be useful to quantify the speed of convergence in terms of properties of the thermodynamic limit state, for example its correlation length etc.

I know that the statement is true if $\Omega$ is a homogeneous irreducible matrix product state (i.e. if it is given in terms of a position independent tensor $(A_i)^{\alpha}_\beta$, and the associated transfer operator is strongly irreducible, but I'm unsure about how to attack the problem more generally.

Comment: This could well be easier to prove for the entanglement entropy rather than the somewhat odd quantity you define. (Is this meant to be a variant of negativity?)  Is that what you are in fact after - a proof that the entanglement converges?

Comment: So i would also be interested whether the (second) entanglement entropy converges, say, for ground states of gapped Hamiltonians. I've seen arguments that the von Neumann entanglement entropy converges, but it used the strong subadditivity. But ultimatively i am more interested in the expression i gave, as at least in case of MPS one gets a discrete topological invariant in this way.

Comment: Strong subadditivity was what I had in mind.  ---  But you might want to check the works of Ogata, she developed tools to generalize MPS-type arguments (as least that's my perception) to general ground states of gapped Hamiltonians, such as for proofs about topological invariants.